# how can i change image for "fb:login-button" when doing facebook login

Tags: facebook, oauth

i have implement facebook OAuth for my application.

I want to change the standard image provided for facebook login and want to put my custom.

[image]

Is there a way to do?

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, but it worths a try:

a. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ , get the code for the Facebook login button. The HTML part is like:

> ```
> <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
> ```

b. Add a new class for that div, and style it.

I myself often don't use the tag Facebook provided though, but instead use their links and re-style it.